# Touch event forwarding in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch-event, uiresponder, uievent

I have a UI component that I want to display in my app, in such a way that any touch event at all dismisses it (though touching the component itself would yield a different result that touching outside of it).

My current solution is to have a custom UIWindow subclass that handles the touch properly and sits on top of the entire screen. However, I don't want the touch to be consumed, but rather forwarded to any UI elements behind  it (i.e. i want the touch to trigger something within the window, but still forward the event along to views behind the window).

The way I tried forwarding the touch events was in -[MyWindow sendEvent:]:

```
NSUInteger superWindowIndex = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows indexOfObject:self];
if (superWindowIndex == 0 || superWindowIndex == NSNotFound) {
    [super sendEvent:event];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows[superWindowIndex - 1] sendEvent:event];
}
```

However, that didn't work as I'd hoped.

What's the best way of achieving what I'm trying to do? Is a UIWindow the right approach?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My solution is not to forward the touch, but include your UI component in another View that cover all UIWindow. Then, you can add TapGesture to the zone outside your main UI.